# Append to a Text File (Not Overwrite!)

Tags: c#, file, append, uwp

Another Universal Platform App question from me, still learning!

Quick question - which method of writing data to a text file do I need to use to append (not overwrite) a string to a text file? Presently I'm using an async void using streams but it's overwriting my files. Here are the different ways of creating and writing to a text file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185401.aspx

Presently this is my code. Does it need modifying to append the data to a text file rather than overwrite it, or do I need to use one of the other methods to append data?

```
//WRITE
        //Create the text file to hold the data
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("tickets.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        //Use stream to write to the file
        var stream = await ticketsFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))
            {
                dataWriter.WriteString("Submitted: " + submitDate + "\n" + "Problem: " + problem + "\n" + "Room: " + location + "\n" + "Description: " + descriptionText.Text + "\n" + "Priority: " + priority + "\n");
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        stream.Dispose(); // Or use the stream variable (see previous code snippet) with a using statement as well.
```

If it makes any difference, my read code:

```
//READ
        //Open the text file
        stream = await ticketsFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        ulong size = stream.Size;

        using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
            {
                uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
                string savedTickets = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);

                textBox.Text = savedTickets;
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)` is the beginning of your file, which is why you are overwriting the entire contents.  You need to get the length of the file and start there instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but when I try and write a string to the file for the first time unless it's 0 it cuts a bit of my string off at the beginning. The length of the string varies too... any other ways of appending?

Answer (score 6):

I don't have a platform in front of me I can test right now, but this should work to get the length of the existing file and put the writer at the end (a new file should return 0):

`using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(stream.Size))`

Comment: Just tried this in a UWP app that logs data to a file and it works, simple solution thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Apart from getting a stream, you can also make use of [FileIO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701440) class. For example method *AppendTextAsync*:

```
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(ticketsFile, "Submitted: " + submitDate + "\n" + "Problem: " + problem + "\n" + "Room: " + location + "\n" + "Description: " + descriptionText.Text + "\n" + "Priority: " + priority + "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, how exactly would I put this code into my program? Sorry I'm a bit novice!

Comment: The best if you have tried it yourself - run and debug your program, see what you get. As a novice you are using streams and *using* statement and you don't know how/where to put the above line?

Comment: Yeah I have tried it. I've put the line `await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(ticketsFile, "Submitted: "` (etc) inside `using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))` but it gives me the error Access is Denied. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @JasonBrown Definitely you are doing something wrong - you et exception because you try to open the file for the second time - first when you open the stream, second with the *FileIO* method. Remove  all the using statement and the line opening the stream, put the line from the answer above the line `//Use stream to write to the file` from your question.

Comment: So the write code reads `/WRITE
            //Create the text file to hold the data
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile ticketsFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("tickets.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(ticketsFile, "Submitted: " + submitDate + "\n" + "Problem: " + problem + "\n" + "Room: " + location + "\n" + "Description:` ? any changes need to be made to read code? That's showing errors. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonBrown Almost anywhere you open a stream from a file, you need `using(stream = await ticketsFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)) { }` statement - if the stream is not closed/disposed - you will likely get access denied exception when attempting to read/write the file again.

Comment: Edit: seems to be working for the time being, thanks @Romasz for your help! If I have any other issues with this I will post back!

Comment: @JasonBrown First of all, once you encounter an issue, try to solve it yourself - debug, do some research. Then if you still haven't found solution, ask another question on SO - comments aren't for asking new questions. Also don't forget to accept answers when they solve your problem.